# How to get Api Controller Uri for getJSON calls?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to get the Url of an API Controller for a getJSON call. The repeated answer I've seen pop up on stack does not work:

```
var elements = [];
$.getJSON("api/MySweetApi/Get", null, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        elements.push(element.ReferenceNumber + " - " + element.Description);
    });
});
```

My ApiController is located in `~/Controllers/api`.

Is there a 'best practice' for handling the link out to an MVC api controller? In a perfect world the answer would hook into the routing engine so that if we decide to move our api controllers to `~/api` it works without us having to make any changes.

My WebApiConfig is:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works:

```
$.getJSON('@Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new RouteValueDictionary{ {"action","Get"}, {"controller", "MySweetApi"}})', null, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        elements.push(element.ReferenceNumber + " - " + element.Description);
    });
});
```

However, it seems really verbose and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Edit : see at the end of the post

The location of your controller file is irrelevent. Basicly, to do thiw you will have to edit your App_Start/RoutConfig.cs and add new routes to tell the routing manager what url to map to what controller. If you have a single API controller, you can do something like this :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MyAPI",
    url: "api/MySweetApi/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "MySweetApi" }
);
```

if you have multiple onese, you can do this :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MyAPI",
    url: "api/{controller}/{action}",
    constraint: new { controller = "MySweetApi|MyOtherSweetApi|MyThirdAPI" }
);
```

If you want to know more about the routing and it's possibilities, check out this great post by John Atten : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Edit : sorry, i thought you were asking about mvc routting.

For my part, i have always used

```
@Url.Action("ControllerName", "ActionName")
```

It should use your routing table to generate the URL so a futur change in your route mapping shouldn't break all your api urls.

Comment: The routing engine isn't being called using my example code. I'm not sure what the best practice is for engaging the routing engine

Comment: At least by default, in a new MVC website, there is a RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); in the Application_Start() of the Global.asax

Comment: When I use Url.Action I get a 404. Does this work for you in getJSON?

Comment: You can also make a centralised js function like urlAPI("MySweetApi","Get") which would return a bulded urls, so you would have to change it only in the fucntion if ever you cange tou url pattern

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are asking about WebAPI.  Since WebAPI, by convention, does not use the action method name, you would need to call the method like this:

```
var elements = [];
$.getJSON("api/MySweetApi/", null, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        elements.push(element.ReferenceNumber + " - " + element.Description);
    });
});
```

This should return all the records in your Get Method on the MySweetApi controller.

Comment: How does the MVC rendering pipeline react to the use of api/MySweetApi for you? Because for me I get a 404 when I use this link. However, http://stackoverflow.com/a/30483132/82333 works because I'm using the pipeline.